# wget downloading tar.gz file as html?

Tags: tar, wget, download

I need to download this file http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u67-b01/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz using wget.

I use the command

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u67-b01/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The file gets downloaded but when I try to untar that file I get this

```
tar -zxvf jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So I use the file command to check on the file and I get this

```
file jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz
jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the file size. You're probably actually getting back HTML. Oracle does not give you the jdk download unless you check the checkbox accepting their terms. (If you look at the reponse headers, you're probably getting back `Content: text/html`)

You can accept the terms by providing the following header:

`--no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"`

Answer (score 1):

Look into the file using `less` and you'll find this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Unauthorized Request</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u67-b01/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz -O
```

This will let you download it as a .tar.gz

[Look at the section of the manual for -O or --output-file=](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)